# How to handle a JSON service that responds with a boolean value?

Tags: json, rest

I want my JSON service to return a boolean value. I know that returning only `true` or `false` is invalid JSON, so what is the best way to do this? I've thought of these options:

```
[true]
```

Or:

```
{ "response": true }
```

I prefer the latter one. Are there any best-practices for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`true`  is a perfectly valid JSON value, it's no worse than `[true]` or `{ "response": true }`. Wrapping it into an object would be a good idea (and object is better than an array), because if one day you decide to add some more data to the response, you won't break all the clients that expect a pure boolean value.

Comment: Actually, `true` is invalid JSON. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627, it states `A JSON text is a serialized object or array.`

Comment: @JustusRomijn: "JSON value" (which is exactly the term I used in my answer) is not the same as "JSON text" your quote mentions. When specifications mention JSON, they mean "JSON value", not "JSON text" as defined in the RFC (JSON.parse, JSON.stringify, JSON serialization librariest etc. generally produce and parse strings of any JSON values).

Comment: yes sorry, you are correct that it is a correct `value`, but it is not valid JSON as you only pass in the value `true`. You can also test it in http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I do appreciate your comment on that using an object is better extendable, and will accept that as a best practice consideration.

Comment: @JustusRomijn: well, I understand your position. Still, the RFC you mention is NOT a standard. The standard is here: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-404.htm (quite fresh) and AFAIU it states that JSON text can be any JSON value, not just an array or object. I don't think this makes any difference, but I would say that jsonlint is simply not standards-compliant (it's "memo compliant").

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ nowadays considers `true` as a valid json.